# Two UIViews for one ViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm not sure how to do this.  So I originally had a ViewController that had one .xib, with one main view.  I present it like this:

```
DogViewController *dvc = [[DogViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DogViewController" bundle:nil];
dvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
dvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:dvc animated:YES];
[dvc release];
```

So that works fine.  However now from a button press in the DogViewController.xib, I want to dismiss the current form sheet, and show another form sheet with some additional questions before proceeding.  So I started by adding another view to in my original .xib of DogViewController, then got stuck in the logic of how to dismiss the first one, and show the second one.  I'm assuming I need some outlet to the new view in the same .xib, but from there I'm lost.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this would be to set it up with a UINavigationController as Mathiew mentions. However, if you really want to transition between two views on one view controller, you can refer to this sample code from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html

The code uses ImageViews to demonstrate the effect but I don't see why you can't use views instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view *within* the other view in front of all of the other objects and just use its `hidden` property to control whether it's shown or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a navigation controller in your modal view, create another xib and do a `[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];`

If you have a good reason, you can set a second view outlet secondView and use code like

```
UIView* superview = [self.view superview];
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
[superview addSubview:self.secondView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution is to hold reference to MainViewController and call methods on it that swap between two view controllers.

Like this:

```
@implementation MainViewController
    - (void)showDogViewController {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        DogViewController *dvc = [[DogViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DogViewController" bundle:nil];
        dvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        dvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        dvc.mainViewController = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:dvc animated:YES];
        [dvc release];
    }

    - (void)showCatViewController {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        CatViewController *cvc = [[CatViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CatViewController" bundle:nil];
        cvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        cvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        cvc.mainViewController = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:cvc animated:YES];
        [dvc release];
    }
}
@end

@implementation DogViewController
    - (void)showCatViewController {
        [mainViewController showCatViewController]
    }
@end

@implementation CatViewController 
    - (void)showDogViewController {
        [mainViewController showDogViewController]
    }
@end
```